# .htaccess redirect everything to "/public" except for "/blog" in subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

i have an .htaccess file to redirect all users to my index.php in /public:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

I want to add a blog to my site as a wordpress subfolder in /blog.

I tried adding:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/blog
```

as a condition, but my site keeps redirecting everything to /public.
Any ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: Where did you put the condition above the second rule or above the first ?

Comment: Maybe creating another `.htaccess` file inside the blog subfolder helps.

Comment: I added the condition above the first rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds pretty straight forward:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

I, personally, would always prefer that notation:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?public/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/?
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /public/index.php?$1 [END,QSA]
```

If that does not work for you, then you will need to start debugging: start monitoring your http server's error log file and also the networking tab inside your browsers console.